# Unable read the pdf file form local system (ng2-pdf-viewer)

Tags: angular, pdf-reader

I want to read the file from the local system. Whenever I am giving path it showing error required "URL" type. But I want to read the file from the local system. And I am new to angular

I search for various sources in the stack overflow but I didn't find any solution

app.compontent.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  pdfSrc: string = 'C:\Users\Karthik\Desktop\pdf-test.pdf';
}
```

app.compontent.html

```
<!--The content below is only a placeholder and can be replaced.-->
<div>
  <label>PDF src</label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="PDF src" [(ngModel)]="pdfSrc">
</div>
<pdf-viewer [src]="pdfSrc" 
          [render-text]="true"
          style="display: block;"
></pdf-viewer>
```

> zone.js:1152 Fetch API cannot load file:///C:/UsersKarthikDesktoppdf-test.pdf. URL scheme must be "HTTP" or "https" for CORS request.

Answer (score 0):

Angular cannot access files out the application scope, you can ask user to browse ( ) the file and process in angular app

Comment: " <input type="file">: